# PHP if/else differences between return and echo?

Tags: php

I am not understanding this ?quirk? of php at all... as I am looking over other peoples code I see that some people leave out the else statement completely and just place a "return false;" statement.

It seems this trick only works for the return statement and as you can see in the cases below it does not work when echoing text.

This is strange, take case two for example, surely this function is read proceeduraly, so the function will return "true" inside the if statement because the condition is met however **when it leaves the if/else statement it should return FALSE because there is no ELSE statement**. This DOES NOT happen and the function still returns true.

I can't make sense of this so hopefully someone can explain?

```
// Case 1
function checkNumber1($number) {
    if ($number === 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$number = 10;
var_dump(checkNumber1($number)); // Returns true






// Case 2
function checkNumber2($number) {

    if ($number === 10) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$number = 10;
echo '<br>';
var_dump(checkNumber2($number)); // Also returns true??






// Case 3
function checkNumber3($number) {
    if ($number === 10) {
        echo 'true' . '<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'false' . '<br>';
    }
}

$number = 10;
echo '<br>';
checkNumber3($number); // Returns true






// Case 4
function checkNumber4($number) {

    if ($number === 10) {
        echo 'true' . '<br>';
    }
    echo 'false' . '<br>';
}

$number = 10;
checkNumber4($number); // Returns true and then false???
```

Comment: In case 2 a `return true` inside your if statement exits the function. In case 4 `echo 'true'` in the if statement does _not_ exit the function, so then `echo 'false'` executes as well.

Comment: I think one big difference which is important here is that `return` ends the function!, while `echo` does not. So Case 1) `10 == 10` -> If statement -> return true -> function end Case 2) `10 == 10` -> If statement -> return true -> function end (Note: Since the return does end the function it will not execute further) Case 3) `10 == 10` -> If statement -> echo true -> function hits end and stops Case 4) `10 == 10` -> If statement -> echo true -> function executes further -> echo false -> function ends

Comment: Crumbs you guys are fast, so return exits a function, brilliant, now I understand! Thank you!

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst You did a good job at testing this and isolating your confusion! Now always when you hit something confusing like this lookup everything (every keyword) in the manual which is involved in this, means: `echo` and `return`.

Comment: Excellent advice, I cant tell you how helpful this is, a small but important thing. Thumbs up!

Comment: @Rizier123 one of us should have just posted an answer and mined some easy rep! =)

Comment: I will accept Riziers comment if he adds it as an answer with pleasure.

Comment: @jszobody Then you should have clicked in the answer box and not comment box, when you wrote your comment ;)

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst Someone already posted an answer and explained what is going on. We don't need to post multiple answers with the same content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return statement in a function [immediately ends execution of the current function and returns control](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).